# npm install EPERM: operation not permitted, chown

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

создаю package.json с помощью команды npm init, потом npm install, и вот что выдает, хотя делаю из под root:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: es6-promise@3.2.1 (node_modules/es6-promise):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/es6-promise-813400e4'

npm ERR! path /mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall chown
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2'
npm ERR!   cause: 
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2'
npm ERR!      errno: -1,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'chown',
npm ERR!      path: '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2' },
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'chown',
npm ERR!   path: '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/bluebird-175e27e2',
npm ERR!   parent: 'hostel' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/esin/.npm/_logs/2017-06-15T06_26_18_690Z-debug.log
```

выключаю всё, что можно выключить, пробую опять -- все равно ошибка.
причем без прав rootа выдает это:

```
npm ERR! path /mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall utime
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json'
npm ERR!   cause: 
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, utime '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json'
npm ERR!      errno: -1,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'utime',
npm ERR!      path: '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json' },
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'utime',
npm ERR!   path: '/mnt/total/projects/goDevelop/nodeProj/hostel/node_modules/.staging/acorn-globals-dbbc1248/package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'hostel' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

посмотрел владельца папки:

```
nelenenovo# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65536 июн 16 09:51 hostel
```

проблема в том, что владелец root:root?

Comment: Вероятно какое-то приложение держит соответствующую папку. Это может быть текстовый редактор, антивирус или еще что подобное. Позакрывать все подозрительное

Comment: Также можно попробовать npm cache clean.

Comment: Посмотрите что у вас с chown

Answer (score 0):

разобрался!
это было следствием моей глупости и неведенья. дело было в том, что проект был создан на автоматически примонтированном разделе через файл fstab с дефолтными настройками, а файловая система -- vfat. по умолчанию он монтировался от root-а, поэтому npm и был в замешательстве. npm init создавал мне package.json без проблем, но npm install выдавал ошибку доступа, хотя я запускал процесс с правами root.
после того, как переписал опции монтирования (uid и gid), все заработало.
всем спасибо за ответы.